# How to trigger an event whenever the variable controlled by an InputField is changed?

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, eventhandler

Consider an an `InputField` object of the form

```
DynamicModule[{x = 0},
 {InputField[Dynamic@x],Dynamic@stuffDependingOnx}
 ]
```

What I want is a direct way to trigger some action, `EventHandler`-style, whenever the value of `x` is changed from inside the `InputField`.

I know that I can use `EventHandler` with `CurrentValue["EventKey"]`, but this triggers whenever I write something inside the input box, not when the value of `x` actually changes.

I could achieve such an effect by using two variables for `x`, say `x` and `xTmp`, setting `xTmp=x` at the beginning and putting a control inside the `Dynamic` to check for equality between `xTmp` and `x`, triggering the event whenever they are different, and then setting them to be equal again.
However, it seems to me that such a basic functionality should be more directly accessible, though I didn't manage to find it on the documentation.

Is there a direct way to do this?

---

#### Some context:

Here is a toy example to illustrate the functionality I'm looking for:

```
DynamicModule[{n = 2},
 DynamicModule[{points = Thread@{Range[0.1, .9, 1/n], 0}},
  Column@{
    InputField[Dynamic@n],
    LocatorPane[
     Dynamic@points,
     Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
       Rectangle[{0, -1}, {1, 1}]}]
     ]
    }
  ]
 ]
```

What I want is to be able to change the `InputField`, and when confirming the change (pressing enter and exiting the focus of `InputField`) the number of points should change, and the new points be reset at their starting positions.

Again, I can achieve this with the trick explained above:

```
DynamicModule[{n = 2, nNew = 2},
 DynamicModule[{points = Thread@{Range[0.1, .9, 1/n], 0}},
  Column@{
    InputField[Dynamic@nNew],
    Dynamic[
     If[nNew != n,
      n = nNew;
      points = Thread@{Range[0.1, .9, 1/n], 0}
      ];
     LocatorPane[
      Dynamic@points,
      Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
        Rectangle[{0, -1}, {1, 1}]}]
      ]
     ]
    }
  ]
 ]
```

which does exactly what I want. But isn't there a more direct way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no killer solution for that. Can you provide a context? Maybe it is not needed, e.g. Dynamic in other places should be smart enough etc. p.s. keep in mind that unless you use `ContinuousAction->True`, `x` is not really changed unless you "finish editing", whatever that means.

Comment: @Kuba see edit .

Comment: @glS `InputField@Dynamic[n, {Automatic, (points = Thread@{Range[0.1, .9, 1/n], 0}) &}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think second argument to `Dynamic` of `InputField` should help you. With it `n` is updated to the changed input and at the same time points are reinitialized. Help on input field says you can't use `ContinuousAction` with general expression, this is why `Number` type is specified.

```
DynamicModule[{n = 2},
 DynamicModule[{make, points},
  make[n_Integer] := RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}];
  points = make[n];
  Column@{
    InputField[
     Dynamic[n, (n = #; points = make[n]) &],
     Number,
     ContinuousAction -> True,
     ImageSize -> 200],
    LocatorPane[Dynamic@points,
     Graphics[{
       FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black],
       Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]},
      ImageSize -> 200]
     ]
    }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This, together with [Kuba's suggestion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120446/how-to-trigger-an-event-whenever-the-variable-controlled-by-an-inputfield-is-cha#comment326246_120446) to only trigger the action when the variable change is complete, answers my question